# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Error authenticating with server

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail through Exchange Server (Office 365) using Java Mail API.
Following is my code:

```
package com.package;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class Mail {

    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("settings", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public void sendMail(String body, String subject, String receipients) throws MessagingException ////this is used to send the emails
    {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());

        message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receipients));
        message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(rb.getString("from")) });

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(body, "text/plain");

        Transport.send(message);
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        System.out.println("Submitter : " + authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    }

    private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

        String username, password;
        public Authenticator() {
            username = rb.getString("from");
            password = rb.getString("password");    
        }

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Mail().sendMail("Testing Mail", "Test", "someuser@ymail.com");
            System.out.println("Mail sent");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Unable to send mail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**When I run this program, the console is showing this :**

```
>>>>>Sending data EHLO HP-WIN8<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data STARTTLS<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data EHLO HP-WIN8<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data AUTH LOGIN<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data ImFzaGZhcS5tZW1vbkBzdHJlZWJvLmNvbSI=<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data IlN1bmlAMTk5MSI=<<<<<<
>>>>>Sending data QUIT<<<<<<
Unable to send mail
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Error authenticating with server)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
    at com.streebo.Mail.sendMail(Mail.java:33)
    at com.streebo.Mail.main(Mail.java:66)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Error authenticating with server
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:402)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:265)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:85)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:70)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:94)
    ... 3 more
```

I have already checked my mail id and password and they are correct, but still I am getting this exception.

Check if I have something wrong in my program, please.

Answer (score 1):

Since i faced the same issue when using test account created gmail.com (provided correct credentials are used) one possible reason could be

You might have used an email hosted / created with gmail / yahoo / hotmail to test.

If you get the javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException, try logging in to the mail account using the credentials, gmail asks you to type a captcha. After successful login you can use the Java mail API to send mails.

The service providers do this to prevent spammers, as for testing we create an account and dont use it for any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Is your resource bundle coming from a properties file?  Does your password have any special characters that might change the way it's interpreted when read from a properties file?  Did you print out your password to make sure it's correct in your program?

Based on the debug output, it appears that you're using the GNU version of JavaMail.  Please try using the [JavaMail reference implementation](http://javamail.java.net/) instead.

Comment: I have tested and my password is printed correctly and it is coming from properties file

Comment: Did you try the JavaMail reference implementation yet?

Comment: I don't understand when you say "I don't know how my problem is solved".  Does that mean your problem **is** solved, but you want to know how?  The simple answer is because there's bugs in the GNU version.